# calculate json values average in python

Tags: python

how can I calculate in python the values JSON file in the following example:

```
"items": [
         {
             "start": "0.6",
             "end": "0.9",
             "alter": [
                 {
                     "conf": "0.6",
                     "content": ""
                 }
             ],
             "type": "pron"
         },
     ]
```

Comment: What did you tried, what worked, what didn't ?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Parsing JSON? Calculating average?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate an average? Do you know how to read a JSON file?  Do you know how to iterate over the data structure above and get the confidence values?  Break the problem into steps and work out how to do each step

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question an hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

with open("./file.json") as f:
    dict_data = json.load(f)  # passing file object and will return json in dictionary datatype
confidences = [float(i['alternatives'][0]['confidence']) for i in dict_data['items']]
confidence_avg = sum(confidences) / len(confidences)
print(confidence_avg)
```

Output:

> 0.8534666666666667

Answer (score -1):

For starters, your JSON file is missing the first and last curly brackets, so I've added them manually. Without them, it is not valid JSON.

Use `json.loads` to parse the JSON string and return a `dict`.

The `confidence` values are stored as strings, so they need to be transformed to `float`s.

Add them one by one and divide by the number of confidence values. In this case we assume each item has only 1.

```py
import json

json_str = r"""{
    "items": [
        {
            "start_time": "0.0",
            "end_time": "0.46",
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": "0.9534",
                    "content": "رسالة"
                }
            ],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        },
        {
            "start_time": "0.46",
            "end_time": "0.69",
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": "0.6475",
                    "content": "اللغة"
                }
            ],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        },
        {
            "start_time": "0.69",
            "end_time": "1.23",
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": "0.9595",
                    "content": "العربية"
                }
            ],
            "type": "pronunciation"
        }
    ]
}"""

items = json.loads(json_str)["items"]

average = 0
for item in items:
    confidence = float(item["alternatives"][0]["confidence"])
    average += confidence

average /= len(items)

print(average)
```

Output:

```
0.8534666666666667
```